# Extract CIE L*a*b* profile from image with PIL

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm benchmarking a few solutions to extract the CIE L*a*b* Colors from images.

When trying to do this with PIL exclusively, I'm getting a weird error:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from PIL import ImageCms
>>> img = Image.open('samples/purple_dress.jpg', 'r')
>>> img.mode
'RGB'
>>> ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, ImageCms.createProfile("sRGB"), ImageCms.createProfile("LAB"))
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PyCMSError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-bcf9d917fcd6> in <module>()
    ----> 1 ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, ImageCms.createProfile("sRGB"), ImageCms.createProfile("LAB"))

    /home/dori/.virtualenvs/computer_vision/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.pyc in profileToProfile(im, inputProfile, outputProfile, renderingIntent, outputMode, inPlace, flags)
        305             imOut = transform.apply(im)
        306     except (IOError, TypeError, ValueError) as v:
    --> 307         raise PyCMSError(v)
        308
        309     return imOut

    PyCMSError: cannot build transform

    >>>
```

I'm using Pillow 2.4.0
Any idea what that means and how to fix it ?

Comment: It seems odd that the traceback from the `raise PyCMSError(v)` didn't display the value of `v` which would tell you which of the three exceptions was raised by the `transform.apply(im)` call. Suggest you  insert a `print v` statement right before the former to get more information on the cause of the error.